# select specific number of results for a column value from DB

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have a table of "messages". In this table I have these columns: `messages(id, from, to, body, new, received_at)`

I want to fetch a collection of all messages but maximum 2 new messages for each of "from";

lets say I have total 50 messages from 3 different unique users. but I want to fetch maximum 2 messages from each user.

I tried to filter results after fetching all messages but I think that is waste of resources. How to do it efficiently with single query?

Comment: Please check this link:- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: thank link is flawed, and could fall prey to the indeterminate order of evaluation of select fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be too complicated to solve using query alone.
Try to get all users first, then iterate over them and get 2 newest messages from them.

Better yet, use eager loading, so it's more efficient. For example:

```
$users = User::with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2);
}])->get();

$users->each(function ($user) {
    // $messages will consists of two most recent messages
    $messages = $user->getRelation('messages');
});
```